# Jenkins UserContent does not execute JS and form HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jenkins

On my project, I need to have an HTML file on jenkins in the directory "userContent" to run a form and send some data to another server :

```
<form id="recievefile" action="http://127.0.0.1:8844/process" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3>Worker</h3>
    <p>
        <select name="workerName">
            <option value="Worker1" selected="selected">Worker1</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <h3>Input</h3>
    <p>
        File: <input id="fileInput" type="file" name="filerecievefile" />
    </p>
    <h3>Options</h3>
    <details>
        <summary>Process type</summary>
        <p>
            <select name="processType">
                <option value="signDocument" selected="selected">Sign document</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </details>
    <input type="text" name="callback" value="?"/>
    <h3>Submit</h3>
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" name="buttonrecievefile" value="Submit" class="buttonFeatured" />
</form>
```

This form is well executed locally, but when I put it in the userContent directory, the form is not executed. Do you know  why ?

Is there any security I can disable to allow form and JavaScript execution on this directory ?

Thx.

Comment: Note: You haven't closed the quotes around "http://127.0.0.1:8844/process" in your form action.

Comment: I changed the url to post it here, in my file I did not forget it.

Answer (score 0):

So, i've found the reason why, it's the CSP (Content Security Policy).

You can disable it in a jenkins configuration file :

> vim /etc/sysconfig/jenkins

Find the line with **JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS** and add the CSP policy like this:

> JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true
> -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src data:;""